# jQuery function is not functional on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mozilla

I have the next code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(formname).each(function () {
            var par_div = $(this).closest("#div"); 
            $(this).validate({
                submitHandler: function (formbeingsubmitted) {
                    $.post('elm_seguicompra.php', $(formbeingsubmitted).serialize(), function (data) {

                        $(formbeingsubmitted).hide("slow");
                        par_div.hide('slow'); //hide the div
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

this function does disappear the forms inside the php while, but has a compability problem with firefox that only effect applies solely in the first form en the list

Comment: Please clarify the value of "formname" here as it appears undefined in this code segment.

Comment: Please also show the associated HTML. We can't really debug your code without knowing what it is trying to affect.

Comment: Are you saing this works in other browsers, or that you've only tested it in Firefox ?

Comment: the form name is formsend

Comment: ^^^ who cares, where is the variable defined, right now it's just a syntax error ?

Comment: no, I'm saying that it works in all browsers less in mozilla

Comment: And where is `var formname = something ???` defined ??

Comment: no, but that it works in all browsers less in mozilla

Comment: I do not know, if you may rewrite the code to run well

Comment: replace `$(formname)` with `$('[name="formsend"]')`